# Shell - LFTP - multiple extensions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, lftp

I have been trying to find a way to use `mget` with only certain file extensions.

I have used following command (which works just fine if I leave `*.csv`)

`lftp -e "set xfer:clobber true;mget $SOURCE_DIR*.{csv,txt,xls,xlsx,zip,rar};exit" -u $SOURCE_USERNAME,$SOURCE_PASSWORD $SOURCE_SERVER || exit 0`

But no luck, I get message `dir/*.{csv,txt,xls,xlsx,zip,rar} no files found`

Tried to add parenthesis

`lftp -e "set xfer:clobber true;mget $SOURCE_DIR(*.{csv,txt,xls,xlsx,zip,rar});exit" -u $SOURCE_USERNAME,$SOURCE_PASSWORD $SOURCE_SERVER || exit 0`

Also no luck

`$SOURCE_DIR` already has a slash `/` at the end

I tried to test lftp locally but I have problem with opening ports on my Vagrant box, hence the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to one FTP without the need to forward ports.

Turns out (I know it seems obvious) you have to specify full path with the wildcard for each extension

`mget $SOURCE_DIR*.csv $SOURCE_DIR*.txt`

separated by space

Also if one (or more) extensions are not found the message "*.txt no files found" will land in standard error, which led me to not be able to proceed with the full script